# Validate Date FORMAT (not date string) using MomentJS?

Tags: validation, date, datetime, format, momentjs

I've seen that you can use an ".isValid()" function to check that a given string is in a date format:

```
moment('2007-05-05', 'YYYY-MM-DD', true).isValid()
```

But is there a way to confirm that the *format* is correct? For example:

`'YYYY-MM-DD'` should return `true`, but

`'YYYY-MM-DDsadsadl'` should return `false` since the characters at the end of the string aren't valid DateTime chars.

We're working on a tool that allows a user to input an existing date format, and then a second input to enter the desired format, but we need validation to ensure the string can properly parse and convert, but they aren't entering a specific date.

The application must accept any and *all* possible date formats.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following function to validate your format.

```
validFormat = function(inputFormat){
  var validation = moment(moment('2017-06-17').format(inputFormat), inputFormat).inspect(); 
  if(validation.indexOf('invalid') < 0) 
    return true; 
  else 
    return false;
}
```

Do spend some time to understand this. This simply does a reverse verification using inspect(). The date `2017-06-17` can be replaced by any valid date.
This [Moment Js Docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/) will help you identify the valid formats.

Just make a call to this function as

```
validFormat('YYYY MM DD')
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! This seems to do the trick. I'll be sure to read up on things, I definitely want to make sure I'm grasping what this function does.

Comment: This always returns `false` for me

Comment: emits a deprecation warning: http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/

Comment: return false for valid date formats like "DD/MM/YYYY"

Answer (score 2):

```js
const getIsValid = inputFormat => moment(moment().format(inputFormat), inputFormat).isValid()
```

**Explanation:**

`moment().format(inputFormat)` - Create a date string from the current time from that format

This is then wrapped with `moment()` to make that string a `moment` date object, defining the format to parse it with. Finally we call the `isValid()` property on that `moment` date object. This ensures we are able to both create and parse a `moment` with our custom format.

Comment: this also DOES emit a deprecation warning

Comment: Considering `moment` is no longer actively developed, I can't imagine there's any trouble. I'm also pretty sure we're using this exact solution in our app and I can't recall seeing any deprecation warning. What's the warning you see?

Comment: Actually we fixed a bug so I've updated the answer to include that fix.

Comment: that does suppress the deprecation warning! and works for complex formats including literals.